# Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. Ef core power tools

Tags: ardalis-cleanarchitecture, ef-core-power-tools

This is the error that I get when I try to add dbcontext diagram using EF Core Power tools

Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1

I have Multiple start up projects. Have tried with just the web as the start up project still get the error. Is there something that I am missing? Am new to Clean Architecture or DDD Patterns

As suggested in [EF Core Power Tools EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException suddenly occurring on "Add DbContext Diagram"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73878473/ef-core-power-tools-entityframeworkcore-design-operationexception-suddenly-occur) Post I have the Context passed as generic parameters, still I get the same error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.